# hook for xml import with wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there an hook for every time a post is created by WP All Import procedure?
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post Save Post hook which is used to create a post in the database.